# How to replace character in files with Ansible?

Tags: replace, syntax, ansible

For this ansible task:

```yaml
- name: wheel sudoers
  shell: sed -i -e "s/# %wheel\tALL=(ALL)\tNOPASSWD: ALL/%wheel\tALL=(ALL)\tNOPASSWD: ALL/g" /etc/sudoers
```

Need to replace `# %wheel\tALL=(ALL)\tNOPASSWD: ALL` with `%wheel\tALL=(ALL)\tNOPASSWD: ALL`.

But this syntax got an error after the first `NOPASSWD:` area:

```
X mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

Why can't I use this syntax?

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/. Long story short (one possible way): `shell: "sed -i -e \"s/# %wheel\\tALL=(ALL)\\tNOPASSWD: ALL/%wheel\\tALL=(ALL)\\tNOPASSWD: ALL/g\" /etc/sudoers"`. Meanwhile, please see below answer, don't use `shell` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all:
You should not use `shell` with `sed` in ansible, but the [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) module.
E.g.:

```yaml
- name: Allow sudo without password
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    regexp: '# %wheel\tALL=\(ALL\)\tNOPASSWD: ALL'
    replace: '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'
```

Check out the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) on how to write a correct regex, espc. for tabs (`\t`) and brackets.
Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359404/ansible-best-practice-for-maintaining-list-of-sudoers) about how to manage sudoers as well.

Second:
Your code is not working because you do not quote your string correctly.
This should work (kudos to [Zeitonautor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator)):

```
shell: "sed -i -e \"s/# %wheel\\tALL=(ALL)\\tNOPASSWD: ALL/%wheel\\tALL=(ALL)\\tNOPASSWD: ALL/g\" /etc/sudoers"
```

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/why-is-sed-not-recognizing-t-as-a-tab/2623007) about using `\t` with `sed`. Using `\t` will not work with every version of `sed`.

Again: Do **NOT** use this! Use the replace module instead!